# doinbackground() method is not called in aync task

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I am trying to upload post from my app to my database. To show the progress dialog when uploading is in progress I am using async task. The doinbackground() method is not executed. :

```
private ProgressDialog mProgress;
public void startPosting() {
//uploading posts
}

post.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Task task=new Task();
             if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
                task.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);
            else
                task.execute();
        }
    });


}

class Task extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>{

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            mProgress = new ProgressDialog(PostActivity.this);

            mProgress.setMessage("Posting Alert");
            mProgress.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            try {
                startPosting();
            }catch (Exception e){

            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {


        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
            mProgress.dismiss();
            Toast.makeText(PostActivity.this, "Alert Posted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


        }
    }


}
```

Any help is appreciated.
Thank you

Answer (score 3):

In `doInBackground()` method you have shown a toast. If you want to show a toast then it must run on the UI Thread. But `doInBackground()` method runs on different thread.

Please remove that toast from there. Maybe one thing you can do that, you can use `runOnUiThread` to show Toast.

Comment: The app is no more crashing but the doinbackground() method is not executing. Because the startposting() method did not executed at all. Only the onpreexecute() and onpostexecute() methods are working.

Comment: The app is not crashing anymore but the doInBackground() method is not executing at all. the startposting() method inside it was suppose to post a new post but nothing happened. It showed the progress dialog which was executed by onPreExecute() method, and the Toast was displayed which was executed by onPostExecute() method. But nothing happened anything in middle which was supposed to be executed by doinbackground().

Comment: Yes..Also, try by removing the code to show the toast.

Comment: protected void onPreExecute() {
            mProgress = new ProgressDialog(PostActivity.this); mProgress.setMessage("Posting Alert");
            mProgress.show();}                                                        
 protected Void doInBackground(Void... void)try {startPosting();}catch (Exception e){Toast.makeText(PostActivity.this,"Error while downloading",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();} return null;}
       
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
            mProgress.dismiss();
            Toast.makeText(PostActivity.this, "Alert Posted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

Comment: You have not removed the toast code from doInBackground()

Comment: its still the same even after removing the Toast.

Comment: protected void onPreExecute() { mProgress = new ProgressDialog(PostActivity.this); mProgress.setMessage("Posting Alert"); mProgress.show();} protected Void doInBackground(Void... void)try {startPosting();}catch (Exception e){Toast.makeText(} return null;} protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) { mProgress.dismiss(); Toast.makeText(PostActivity.this, "Alert Posted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); – Madhu Banerjee 3 mins ago

Comment: Debug it. Maybe some exception is thrown.

Answer (score 0):

replace your async task class code with this code in your app.

```
//=====================================================================================
// Async Task Class
//=====================================================================================

public class LazyDataConnection extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    String method;

    public LazyDataConnection(String method) {
        this.method = method;
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {
        method = arg0[0];
        return getData.callWebService_2(arg0[0], arg0[1]);
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String xmlResponse) {

        if (xmlResponse.equals("")) {
            try {
                if (progDialog != null && progDialog.isShowing()) {
                    progDialog.dismiss();
                }
            } catch (Exception ex) {
            }
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No Internet Connection", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else if (method.equals("METHOD NAME")) { // method name
            try {
                if (progDialog != null && progDialog.isShowing()) {
                    progDialog.dismiss();
                }
            } catch (Exception ex) {
            }

            METHOD NAME(xmlResponse, "METHOD NAME");
            if (complaint_id != 0) {
                finish();
            }

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), alertmessage, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    }
```

`

if any query ask me.

Answer (score 0):

An asynchronous task is defined by a computation that runs on a background thread and whose result is published on the UI thread. An asynchronous task is defined by 3 generic types, called Params, Progress and Result, and 4 steps, called onPreExecute, doInBackground, onProgressUpdate and onPostExecute.

You cannot update UI as well as perform any UI operation on the background thread. `doInBackground()` is invoked on the background thread.

`onPreExecute()`,`onPostExecute(Result)`, are invoked on the UI thread. So you can display toast here.

Answer (score 0):

You can not directly use the context in doInBackground() because it runs in background and the background thread can not change the UI appearance,
Instead of this, you can make Toast in `onPreExecute()` or `onPostExecute(Result)`

If you face error in

`Toast.makeText(PostActivity.this,"Error while downloading",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();`

For that you can also use the  `getApplicationContext()` method or create context variable.

```
Context c;
......
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ...
        c = this;
        ...
}
......
class Task extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>{
.......
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
            mProgress.dismiss();
            Toast.makeText(c, "Alert Posted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            //OR
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Alert Posted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove Toast from the doInBackground() and put the either in onPostExecute() or run the toast in  runonUIthread()

Comment: The app is not crashing anymore but the doInBackground() method is not executing at all. the startposting() method inside it was suppose to post a new post but nothing happened. It showed the progress dialog which was executed by onPreExecute() method, and the Toast was displayed which was executed by onPostExecute() method. But nothing happened anything in middle which was supposed to be executed by doinbackground().

Answer (score 0):

Enclose everything in `onPostExecuted()` with `runOnUIThread()`:

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
@Override
public void run() {

}});
```